# Select a range of cells between rows with designated values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to format a large text file in Excel. It looks similar to this to begin with:

```
Headings  
----------  
Data   
Data 
Data  
ENDROW  
Other Information
```

I want to select the cells between ---------- and ENDROW and then use the text to columns function on the selected cells. I recorded a macro for the text to columns bit and eventually I want to use this to loop throughout the entire document.

```
 Sub findRange()
 Dim nRow As Long
 Dim nStart As Long, nEnd As Long

' Figure out where the range should start.
For nRow = 1 To 65536
If Range("A" & nRow).Value = "----------" Then
nStart = nRow
Exit For
End If
Next nRow

' Figure out where the range should end.
For nRow = nStart To 65536
If Range("A" & nRow).Value = "ENDROW" Then
nEnd = nRow
Exit For
End If
Next nRow
nEnd = nEnd - 1

Range("A" & nStart & ":D" & nEnd).Select
   Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
       FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(27, 1), Array(56, 1), _
       Array(59, 1), Array(60, 1), Array(73, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
   Selection.ColumnWidth = 16.33
   Range("B:B,F:F,D:D,H:H").Select
   Range("H1").Activate
   Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

It's erroring out and any input is appreciated. I am a novice trying to learn my way into this.

Comment: What are the values of nStart and nEnd just before the line      Range("A" & nStart & ":D" & nEnd).Select

Comment: When it errors out, it should give you a specific error message and also the option to "debug".  If you can click the debug button and make note of which line of code is causing the issue, then edit your question to add the specific error message and line of code that causes it, that would help immensely.

Comment: quicker startrow (same idea can be used for the endrow): `nStart=range("A1:A65535").find("----------", LookAt:=xlWhole).Row` - much quicker than checking each cell

Comment: It was giving me a Range error on the "If Range("A" & nRow).Value = "ENDROW" Then" line. I replaced all the "----------" with "STARTROW" and it worked. I realized it wasn't locating any of the dashes. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Microsoft only can convert one column at a time. Try to replace
    Range("A" & nStart & ":D" & nEnd).Select
With
    Range("A" & nStart & ":A" & nEnd).Select
And, Loop through the other three columns.

Comment: That was part of the issue, I cleaned all that up and then realized the dashes were giving me trouble.